# timezone cannot be changed in Linux CentOS

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I have changed the timezone settings in loaded PHP ini file to this:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "America/Santiago"
```

I restarted httpd service and then loaded an info.php page that has only phpinfo() method call. For my surprise, Default timezone still appears as UTC.

I have changed other php.ini files besides loaded file, but no success.

However, if I use command line php, it shows correct timezone.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check the output of the `phpinfo` command to verify you are modifying the correct php.ini file. Look for a directive to indicate the file being processed. When PHP is served through a web server, there is often a separate configuration file.

Comment: @CosmicOssifrage I have modified the INI file shown in Loaded Configuration File

Comment: Any chance it's being overridden by another .ini file in e.g. `/etc/php.d` or that there is a `.htaccess` file in your directory that's overriding it?